# Синхронизация папки с удалённой через ftp cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо синхронизировать директории на локальном и удалённом компьютерах используя ftp, но с условием, что скрипт будет запускаться на windows с минимальным количеством дополнительных программ. В идеале — только средствами встроенных, как ftp (wget не очень хочется использовать). Устанавливать ПО на сервер нет возможности.

Пока что я придумал такой алгоритм действий:
1. Записываю (руками) начало ftp-команд с адресом сервера, логином, паролем и переходами до нужной «корневой папки» на удалённом сервере.
2. Генерирую список файлов, которые есть у меня сейчас на локальном компьютере, дописывая к началу get (newer не смог заставить работать).
3. Конкатенирую эти файлы в единый scriptFile
4. Запускаю ftp -v -n -s:scriptFile
5. Жду выполнения и удаляю сконкатенированный файл scriptFile

Есть следующая проблема. У меня есть две папки, которые не должны записываться в файл на втором этапе. Назовём их `.temp1` и `.temp2`. На сервере также есть папки, которые мне не нужны. Назовём их upload и cache. При этом, постоянно появляются файлы, которых на локальном компьютере у меня нет, а хотелось бы получить.

Я нашёл команду `dir /A-D /B /S "./"`, но она выводит не то, что необходимо: все файлы с путями относительно корня файловой системы (C:\dir.temp2\sample.txt). Ну и исключить директории нельзя.

Тогда я обратился к команде `forfiles /P . /S /M * /C "cmd /c echo get @relpath"`. В целом, она уже выводит всё то, что мне необходимо, но всё ещё не умеет игнорировать файлы. Не знаю, можно ли написать в нём какое-то условие, поэтому, я [нашёл такой способ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755559/forfiles-command-ignore-a-directory): заходить в папки и выполнять forfiles прямо там.

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("\dir\*.*") do (
    if /I not "%%D"=="\dir\.temp1" (
        chdir "%%D"
        forfiles /P . /S /M * /C "cmd /c echo get @relpath"
        cd ../
    )
)
```

Я не очень понимаю в какую сторону теперь двигаться. Подскажите, как доработать скрипт. Может, я не верно выбрал алгоритм и лучше вообще написать `promt`, `mget`. И вообще, знатоки, скажите сработает ли `get ".\subdir\sample.txt"` в ftp? Не нужно ли предварительно переходить в каталог?

И ещё одна ситуация, у меня сейчас выводятся адреса так: `".\subdir\sample.txt"`, мне кажется, что надо заменить `.\` на `\`. Нашёл только способ, с помощью переменной: `set str=%str:find=replace%`. Может, что-то получше есть?

Comment: А может Вам посмотреть в сторону WSH?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov очень хорошее предложение, только я ещё меньше знаю про любой из языков доступных в WSH. Вероятно, там всё классно и просто, но где учиться даже не подозреваю, к сожалению=(

Comment: MSDN. Поверьте, будет значительно проще. А JScript - он почти Си